# Metro is not getting connected to Android Emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, metro-bundler

My Metro bundler is not getting connected to the android emulator

Please help

When i run the command to build react native app , it does not automatically start my android emulator , nor does it recognises it

Answer (score 1):

good day. you have to follow all the steps in the react native official documentation to make it run.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup